# redefine section style with titleformat

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want to define my own section style by titlesec package, just after in a chapter, the section title show chapter title and section title.

Simple code example:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filleft}
{\chaptername~ \thechapter}{1em}{\bf}[\vspace{-0.6em}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}]
%
%
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filleft}
{\thesection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-0.6em}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch01}
\section{sec01}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution changing the definition of `\chapter` to save the current chapter name in a macro and reuse it in the section title's format:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xparse}


\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filleft}
{\chaptername~ \thechapter}{1em}{\bfseries}[\vspace{-0.6em}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}]

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Current@Chapter{}
\let\CHAPTERBAK\chapter
\newcommand\star@processor[1]
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\def\ProcessedArgument{*}}
      {\def\ProcessedArgument{}}%
  }
\newcommand\opt@processor[1]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\ProcessedArgument{}%
    \else
      \def\ProcessedArgument{[#1]}%
    \fi
  }
\RenewDocumentCommand \chapter { >{\star@processor}s >{\opt@processor}O{} m }
  {%
    \gdef\Current@Chapter{\chaptername~\thechapter\ #3}%
    \CHAPTERBAK#1#2{#3}
  }

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filleft}
{\Current@Chapter\ \thesection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-0.6em}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{ch01}
\section{sec01}
\end{document}
```

**Explanation:**

First we define a macro which we'll use to save the current chapter's name and number. This is done with `\newcommand*\Current@Chapter{}`. I use `\newcommand` to make sure there is no conflict, as `\newcommand` checks whether the macro's name is already defined.

Next we'll save the current definition of `\chapter` into a macro called `\CHAPTERBAK` with `\let\CHAPTERBAK\chapter`.

I then define two macros just to parse the arguments to the new `\chapter` definition. Those two are called `\star@processor` and `\opt@processor`. `\star@processor` will get the star-argument of `\chapter` (so the optional `*`). and `\opt@processor` will get the argument in optional brackets. In the macro definition `#1` will be what `\ProcessedArgument` was defined to in `\star@processor` and `#2` what `\ProcessedArgument` was in `\opt@processor`.

The `xparse` package's `\NewDocumentCommand` gives us an easy interface to define new commands. We can use argument processors by using `>{\<processor>}` as a prefix of an argument defining token. The `\<processor>` should take one argument which is the argument given. You could however use a macro taking two arguments and prefixing with `>{\<processor>{<first argument>}}`, the second argument would then be the argument given to the macro which is to be defined.

An `s` argument is an optional star and if it was present (so `\chapter*` was used) the test `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` will expand the true-branch, so `\def\ProcessedArgument{*}` is used by `\star@processor`.

The `O{}` type argument is an optional argument in brackets which defaults to be empty (you could give other defaults in the braces). If it is empty `\ProcessedArgument` will be defined to be empty by `\opt@processor`, else the argument will be set to `[#1]` so `#2` in the new `\chapter` macro will be either empty or an argument delimited by brackets.

Now we can easily define `\chapter` to do what we want. First it'll redefine `\Current@Chapter` to contain `\chaptername~\thechapter\ #3` with `#3` being the mandatory argument to `\chapter`. After that `\chapter` calls the original `\chapter` as `\CHAPTERBAK`.

In `\titleformat{\section}` we can now include `\Current@Chapter` in the prefix.

Comment: Although I don’t know the principle, it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: @zongxian I've added an exhaustive (and hopefully comprehensible) explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helpful to me for learning macros.

Comment: @zongxian forgot to mention `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, the first changes `@` to be considered as a character so that it is possible to use in macro names, the latter changes it back to be of type "other".